# CSS horizontal scroll, but vertical stretch?

Tags: css

I'm making a list of routes for workers. Each worker has one route, and inside the route are any number of work orders. There can be anywhere from 1-10 routes (corresponding to 1-10 workers) and up to 100 work orders in a single route.

Each list of work orders is a `sortable` list of `divs`. Work orders can be rearranged within a route, or dragged over to a different route. What I have is a parent `div` inside of which are all the child route `divs`. I want the parent `div` to only allow route `divs` to be displayed in a line, horizontally. As we hit 6 or more routes, the parent window should scroll horizontally, and disallow a second row of work orders.

It should look like this (R=Route with * representing a work order):

```
R  R  R  R  R
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *     *  *
*  *     *
*  *
   * 
   *
```

It should *not* look like this:

```
R  R  R
*  *  *
*  *  *
*  *   
*  *     
*  *
   * 
   *
R  R
*  *
*  *
*  *
*
```

So, the routes should be shown horizontally, with a scroll bar if there are too many to fit on the page. BUT, the parent `div` containing these routes can grow vertically to allow for long routes that have many work orders.

I've tried adding various CSS styles to the parent `div` all to no avail. The closest I got was to set a `max-height` setting to the parent div which forces horizontal scrolling. However that means that routes get cut off vertically if they are too long.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As [CSS-Tricks mentions](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/), the best approach might be to use tables. Check out this fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyz3m7cx/1/

```
.container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will also help organize your data which would probably be better in table cells. Tables get a bad rap but definitely have their uses.

The other option which I don't recommend is to have the inner container's width set. This would get annoying if width changes but you could set it using jQuery. It'll probably be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Oh that's a great idea. Indeed, tables can be very helpful to keep things firmly organized when divs get messy.

Comment: No, it didn't actually. I can't help but wonder if there's something more going on. I'm using the 960grid system, and in my current window I have a parent, and two children. In one of these children is where I and adding my table. I'm also wondering if the fact that I'm adding routes dynamically, after the `$(document).ready()` if that's causing me problems. I can't replicate your fiddle on my page.